# Iterating over dataframe doesn't give expected result

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Iam importing a column of csv file using `pandas.read_csv()` to my python script.

Iam doing like :

```
data = pandas.read_csv(path)
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

Why does it print only first element of the column ?

and when i convert it to a numpy array using `npdata = np.array(data)`and when i print it, it prints everything except first element.

Actually what iam trying to do is to load a time-date column from a csv file and want to do some feature engineering but i have problem i loading it correctly.

Comment: Try: `print(data)`

Comment: You have no issue loading it correctly. Your issue is how you process the data. Conventionally, use `print(data.head())` to see what you loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, iterating over `data` will imply iteration over the column names, which you're not looking for.

To iterate over rows, use [`df.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) instead:

```
data = pandas.read_csv(path)
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

---

MCVE:

```
print(df)

   A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10

for d in df:
    print(d)

A
B

for i, d in df.iterrows():
    print(d['A'], d['B'])

1  2
3  4
5  6
7  8
9  10
```

---

As mentioned in comments, if all you want to do is take a peek at your data, print out [`df.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
print(df.head(3)) # the arg is any > zero value signifying the number of rows

   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

Comment: Np. Nice answer otherwise.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Does it imply that one of the columns is becoming the index? Your answer is factually correct, but I'm not sure it addresses the question after re-reading it

Comment: @roganjosh Look at it like this. OP tried something. OP got something. OP expected something else. It's very possible there's error in their wording but I'm pretty sure this is what they wanted and it addresses the same.

Comment: Well, I will look at it as my own logic dictates, thanks. In this instance, I'm not sure what the OP is asking.

Comment: @roganjosh Okay, go ahead and write an answer addressing what you think needs addressing....

Comment: @roganjosh From what I understand `Why does it print only first element of the column ?` means `why is it printing only the column headers?`

Comment: @roganjosh And, `it prints everything except first element.` means `it prints everything ____except___ those headers`. These are classic symptoms of a common misunderstanding, nothing is cause for confusion here.

Comment: I can't answer a question I don't get, and I never intended for this to become awkward (I don't dispute thr correctness of your answer and never did; I could down vote if I wanted to). I just wonder whether there's more behind the question.

Comment: @roganjosh I understand, and I respect your opinion. I'm just trying to reason with you (read: the two comments above). Only OP can clarify things now.

Comment: There is no column header i just need to take care of values. i took care of headers using skiprows = 1 attribute.

Comment: further on trying your way.. it thows a TypeError saying 'method' object is not iterable.

Comment: @mcjoshi Sorry... it works for me. No clue what your issue could be.

Comment: it works now.. solved :) suppose if each element is of form '19-05-2017', how do i extract only month part from it. Avoid using "re" and linear scan.

Comment: Convert it to datetime and extract: `df.ColName.apply(pd.datetime).dt.month`

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake :)